# I give you ascii-art, you make it pseudo-3d

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, unicode, 3d

Do you know the optical effect of a tridimensional hand painted whit horizontal lines?
[Examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=mano%20tridimensional%20pintada%20con%20lineas%20horizontales&rlz=1C1CHBF_esES920ES920&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjP8e-v99DwAhVDUhoKHW1tARkQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1920&bih=937#imgrc=twMWoWZ6Msj0EM)

This challenge consists of making something like that effect with ascii, and transforming one 2d input into a "3d" output.

### The algorithm

To perform this transformation, you first replace all `1` with a `¯` and all `0` with a `_`. In order to make things more realistic, you should replace a `¯` that does not have another `¯` before it with `/`, and a `¯` that does not have another `¯` after it with `\`.

Some examples:

```
Input:
001111100

Output:
__/¯¯¯\__
```

```
Input:
0110
1111

Output:
_/\_
/¯¯\
```

^ In this case, there are multiple lines, so apply this to all lines.

```
Input:
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000111100000000000001111100000
000000111110000000000111111000000
000000111111000000011111100000000
000000111111000001111110000000000
000000011111100011111100000000000
000000111111111111111100000000000
000000111101111111011110000000000
000000111100111110011110000000000
000000111111111111111110000000000
000000111111111111111110000000000
000000001111111111110000000000000
000000000001111100000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000

Output:
_________________________________
______/¯¯\_____________/¯¯¯\_____
______/¯¯¯\__________/¯¯¯¯\______
______/¯¯¯¯\_______/¯¯¯¯\________
______/¯¯¯¯\_____/¯¯¯¯\__________
_______/¯¯¯¯\___/¯¯¯¯\___________
______/¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯\___________
______/¯¯\_/¯¯¯¯¯\_/¯¯\__________
______/¯¯\__/¯¯¯\__/¯¯\__________
______/¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯\__________
______/¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯\__________
________/¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯\_____________
___________/¯¯¯\_________________
_________________________________
```

Exceptions / rules:

- The input will never have a single positive cell in a row (e.g. `00100`)
- You can consider other characters for the input. However, it should only be two characters and not the same characters that the output uses. For instance:

```
Valid input:    0001111000 # two characters, different from the output
Valid input:    aaiiaiiaaa # two characters, different from the output
Valid input:    ,€€€€,,,,, # two characters, different from the output
Invalid input:  0001223000 # four different characters are used.
Invalid input:  ___1111___ # invalid, because the output uses underscores.
Invalid input:  ///\\\\/// # both slash and backslash are used by the output.
```

- The output must use the four characters described above and **only** those four. Alternatively, you may use `-` instead of the macron (`¯`)
- The macron (upper character) has a codepoint of 175, but you may count it as one byte.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: I like the test cases, but could you also describe the algorithm? (if I'm understanding correctly, change `1`s to macrons, `0`s to underscores, `_¯` to `_/`, and `¯_` to `\_`)

Comment: This isn't "ascii-art" as a macron (`¯`) isn't ASCII. Additionally, you should provide an explanation as when to convert to `/` and `\`. It seems to be at the first and last `1`s of each row, but that isn't clear

Comment: I think this is a cool challenge, but unfortunately it's underspecified right now. A description of the actual algorithm to generate the output is needed. Also, ^; it's fine to include that but it can't be ascii-art in that case and I'd recommend allowing answers to include it for 1 byte, or just use `-` or something

Comment: I've fixed the spec for you since I think it's quite obvious what you mean, so I've reopened this. Please let me know if anything is incorrect with this. For the future, I would definitely recommend using [the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/); it's a good way to get great ideas like this into clearly formatted great challenges. +1 to this though!

Comment: The test case `1111` -> `/¯¯\ ` does not match the spec from the first paragraph.  It implies there is another rule like "for the first and last characters, convert `¯` to `/` and `\ `.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Jonah Oops, let me fix that

Comment: @nph It was actually edited since my comment.  It's fine now.

Comment: OP and @hyper-neutrino can you confirm what `010` is supposed to return?  From the examples I would suspect `/¯\ `, but the spec in the first paragraph kind of "errors" on it (because the same thing is getting replaced twice).  Also the existing answers do not agree, and none of them returns my guess for what's right.

Comment: @Jonah from the rules near the bottom, `The input will never have a single positive cell in a row`

Comment: You could use the overline character instead: `_/‾‾‾\_` looks a bit better than `_/¯¯¯\_`...

Comment: @ago (ºoº) Thanks, i didnt know that caracter, i take note for the next time, now its a little bit late for changue it in this challenge

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
Ż<ƝoḤU)⁺ị“\/Ø-_”
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///obptjc/Mf7lgSqvmocdfD3d2PGubE6B@eoRv/qGHu/4e7t9gCacNDO4@1H26P5Hq4czGQW3O4/VHTmqxHjfu4uP7/NzAwBAEDA64aLiDTgAvEA7EJAagKiGYkYAgX4UIXQHANMcyAK0HhYFFhiGYeF7o@dAWoZiAADr/AZLHaAhE0RFAEbSFHBaoabKGOLWCxqMAOAA)

Uses hyphens instead of macrons. Takes a good deal of inspiration from hyper-neutrino's answer, so don't forget to send him some votes. Feels like there's got to be some way to shave a byte off the string at the end, with the right replacement for `oḤ`...

```
      )            For each line,
       ⁺           twice:
Ż                  prepend a 0,
  Ɲ                then for each pair of neighboring elements
 <                 is the second greater than the first?
   o               Replace zeroes with corresponding elements of
    Ḥ              the line doubled,
     U             and reverse.
        ị          Modular 1-index into
         “\/Ø-_    "\/Ø-_".
                   (0 -> _, 1 -> \, 2 -> /, 4 -> -)
```

Answer (score 15):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), Score 25

26 bytes, but scoring `¯` as 1, as per note in challenge.

```
s|1(1*)1|/\1\\|g
y/01/_¯/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/uMZQw1BL07BGP8YwJqYmnatS38BQP/7Qev3//w0MDEHAwICLC8gy4AJxgExCAKoCohUJGMJFuNAFEFxDDDPgSlA4WFQYopnHha4PXQGqGQiAwy8wWay2QAQNERRBW8hRgaoGW6hjC1gsKrCDf/kFJZn5ecX/dYsA)

Answer (score 11):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>26</s> 19 bytes

```
1(1*)1
/$.1$*¯\
0
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fUMNQS9OQS19Fz1BF69D6GC4Drvj//w0MDEHAwICLC8gy4AJxgExCAKoCohUJGMJFuNAFEFxDDDPgSlA4WFQYopnHha4PXQGqGQiAwy8wWay2QAQNERRBW8hRgaoGW6hjC1gsKrADAA) Link includes test cases. Edit: Saved 7 bytes with inspiration from @DigitalTrauma. Explanation:

```
1(1*)1
/$.1$*¯\
```

Replace a run of `1`s with a run of `¯`s between `/` and `\`.

```
0
_
```

Replace `0`s with `_`s.

(Note that Retina uses the ISO-8859-1 code page, so `¯` is 1 byte anyway.)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Thanks, I've actually used a more Retina-y approach for the same byte count.

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-p -Mutf8`), 25 bytes, score 24

```perl
s|1(1*)1|/\1\\|g;y;01;_¯
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4xlDDUEvTsEY/xjAmpibdutLawNA6/tD6//8NDAxBwMCAiwvIMuACcYBMQgCqAqIVCRjCRbjQBRBcQwwz4EpQOFhUGKKZx4WuD10BqhkIgMMvMFmstkAEDREUQVvIUYGqBluoYwtYLCqwg3/5BSWZ@XnF/3UL/uv6lpakWQAA)

Same as [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma)'s [sed answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225829/70745), except the trick using semicolon delimiter the last character can be removed.

Answer (score 8):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 80 bytes

```
/0/_//1/a//aaa/a-a//-aa/--a//aa-/a--//-a-/---//a-/\\\/-//-a/-\\\\//aa/\\\/\\\\/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZExCsAgDEV37xK@uY9QMhQ6dPP@2KhU0UaEZsnP85tgjLfE64wpweMAGAKICIRUkAqiQkgJZUJKVGgOIaAgUMhaXYWVIvlduJpYY@DciJtBL/nTo1mGwnDw1M/N92bD2KPH4i3vqTmlQu5pO@WPY/RYW7cWazgWP5ce)

Uses `-` instead of the macron, as it is allowed.

I'm marking it as 80 bytes because of the required newline at the end of the input.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 80 bytes (but actually 79 because ¯ is counted as a 1 byte char in this challenge)

```python
import re
while r:=re.sub:print(r(*"0_",r(*"1¯",r("1(1*)1",r"/\1\\",input()))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRKEolas8IzMnVaHIyrYoVa@4NMmqoCgzr0SjSENLySBeSQdEGx5aD2IoGWoYamkaAplK@jGGMTFKOpl5BaUlGpog8P@/gaGhAZchEHBxGRACUBUg1SjihnARLnQBBNcQwwy4EhQOFhWGaOZxoetDV4BqBgLg8AtMFqstEEFDBEXQFnJUoKrBFurYAhaLCuwAAA)

Because we love `re.sub` :)

### Old solution : 94 bytes (but actually 93, you know the song ...)

I don't know why but I thought a pure vanilla python solution would beat a solution using regex ... I was wrong.

```python
while r:=str.replace:print(r(r(r(r(f"0{input()}0","10","\\0"),"01","0/")[1:-1],*"1¯"),*"0_"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/vzwjMydVocjKtrikSK8otSAnMTnVqqAoM69EowgK05QMqjPzCkpLNDRrDZR0lAxBREyMgZKmjpKBIZBtoK@kGW1opWsYq6OlZHhoPVBCS8kgXklT8/9/A0NDAy5DIODiMiAEoCpAqlHEDeEiXOgCCK4hhhlwJSgcLCoM0czjQteHrgDVDATA4ReYLFZbIIKGCIqgLeSoQFWDLdSxBSwWFdgBAA)

Nothing too crazy here, just a few `str.replace`, and some `str.replace` and even more `str.replace`

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
ŒgḤ1¦€N0¦€)ị“-/\_”
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opPSHO5YYHlr2qGmNnwGY0ny4u/tRwxxd/Zj4Rw1z/z/cvSUMKApEh9sj//83IAS4IJQhEKCIG8JFuNAFEFxDDDPgSlA4WFQYopnHha4PXQGqGQiAwy8wWay2QAQNERRBW8hRgaoGW6hjC1gsKrADAA)

Inputs a matrix of `0` and `1`s, outputs a list of lines. Uses `-` instead of a macron

### How it works

```
ŒgḤ1¦€N0¦€)ị“-/\_” - Main link. Takes a matrix M on the left
          )        - Over each row R in M:
Œg                 -   Group adjacent equal elements in R
     €             -   Over each group G in R:
  Ḥ                -     Double:
   1¦              -     The first value
         €         -   Over each group G in R:
      N            -     Negate:
       0¦          -     The last value
                        For zeros, these are left unchanged.
                        For ones, the first becomes 2 and the last -1
            “-/\_” - Yield the string "-/\_"
           ị       - Index, 1 based and modularly. This means that:
                       1 or -3 -> -
                       2 or -2 -> /
                       3 or -1 -> \
                       4 or  0 -> _
```

Comment: o.O https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: (+1) how did you answer?

Comment: @ophact [I didn't reload the page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363622/355458)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing but, once, I was writing an answer to an SO question which was closed while I was typing. Inspecting and trying to make the button clickable did not seem to work and so I could not post.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
Ż;0ṡ3Ḅ)ị“_./__\-_”
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///obmuDhzsXGj/c0aL5cHf3o4Y58Xr68fExuvGPGub@f7h7S9ijpjVAdLg98v9/A0KAC0IZAgGKuCFchAtdAME1xDADrgSFg0WFIZp5XOj60BWgmoEAOPwCk8VqC0TQEEERtIUcFahqsIU6toDFogI7AAA)

Uses `-` instead of the macron

```
Ż;0ṡ3Ḅ)ị“_./__\-_”  Main Link; takes a matrix of bits and outputs a list of lines
      )             For each row
Ż                   Prepend 0
 ;0                 Append 0
   ṡ3               Get overlapping slices of length 3
     Ḅ              Convert from binary
                 // basically, the center of the 3-slice is the character itself
                 // and we need the left and right context to determine if it needs
                 // to be changed. So ___, __-, -__, and -_- (0, 1, 4, 5) become _,
                 // _-- (3) becomes /, --_ (6) becomes \, and --- (7) stays as -
       ị“_./_.\-_”  index into "_./_.\-_", so 1=_ 3=/ 4=_ 5=_ 6=\ 7=- 0=_
                 // note that Jelly is 1-indexed and indexes wrap around
```

Answer (score 5):

## Excel (Insider Beta), <s>139</s> 96 bytes

```
=LET(s,LAMBDA(t,x,y,SUBSTITUTE(t,x,y)),s(s(s(s(s(A2,101,"\_/"),10,"\_"),0&1,"_/"),0,"_"),1,"-"))
```

Had to spend quite a few bytes shortening the `SUBSTITUTE` function.  Originally, I thought you had to adapt to any two characters which is what I did below.

```
=LET(s,LAMBDA(t,x,y,SUBSTITUTE(t,x,y)),a,LEFT(A2),b,LEFT(s(s(A2,a,""),"
","")),s(s(s(s(s(A2,b&a&b,"\_/"),b&a,"\_"),a&b,"_/"),a,"_"),b,"-"))
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 54 bytes<sup>*</sup>

*<sup>* by counting the macron as 1 byte, as allowed in this challenge</sup>*

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>'_/¯\\'[c*=!+s[i+1]-~s[i-1]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZBBTsQgFIb3nAJXgJ1SWBu60wvMctoYwtCKIVChmhijV/IOXqy2GWdqK5NJ/DeP//Hxv/Ae5YuMKpiuz53f66ERQxRlpEF3ViqNC1q0G6w2hogS3Rdfn1WFdupaXGVxZzJe5x9jzXldkyHop2cTNEZNRGQMkPs7Y/X21SnMCO39tg/GtZjQ2FnTY1S5yo1g48OtVA84QlHCNwCh8i56q6n1LW5wJDCDaCJvwDsZGOOTGANgqgCMnh2Pl/RDHAJ@iZ86YN2YLf@TcUIWJkHwVR5Yv1sDy4xZZ/5yvE1OOTT5XC5O@Q@xZFJbTy02QaT1DQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 24 bytes

```
εγεS¬·0ǝR¬(0ǝR}˜"_¯/\"sè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V/z/9zWc5vPbQ0@tObQdoPjc4MOrdEAUbWn5yjFH1qvH6NUfHjF/1qvQ7v/GxACXBDKEAhQxA3hIlzoAgiuIYYZcCUoHCwqDNHM40LXh64A1QwEwOEXmCxWWyCChgiKoC3kqEBVgy3UsQUsFhXYAQA) Takes input as a list of lines of ones and zeros and outputs as a list of lists of characters in each line.

```
εγεS¬·0ǝR¬(0ǝR}˜"..."sè  # trimmed program
                         # implicit input...
ε                        # with each element replaced by...
                      è  # list of characters in...
                "..."s   # literal...
                      è  # with indices in...
               ˜     s   # flattened...
 γ                       # list of groups of consecutive equal elements in...
                         # (implicit) current element in map...
  ε                      # with each element replaced by...
             R           # reversed...
        R                # reversed...
   S                     # list of characters in...
                         # (implicit) current element in map...
       ǝ                 # with element at index...
      0                  # literal...
       ǝ                 # replaced with...
    ¬                    # first element of...
   S                     # list of characters in...
                         # (implicit) current element in map...
     ·                   # doubled...
             ǝ           # with element at index...
            0            # literal...
             ǝ           # replaced with...
          ¬              # first element of...
        R                # reversed...
   S                     # list of characters in...
                         # (implicit) current element in map...
       ǝ                 # with element at index...
      0                  # literal...
       ǝ                 # replaced with...
    ¬                    # first element of...
   S                     # list of characters in...
                         # (implicit) current element in map...
     ·                   # doubled...
           (             # negated
               }         # exit map
                         # (implicit) exit map
                         # implicit output
```

`R}` can also be a `}í` with no change in functionality: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V/z/9zWc5vPbQ0@tObQdoPjc4MOrdEAUrWH156eoxR/aL1@jFLx4RX/a70O7f5vQAhwQShDIEARN4SLcKELILiGGGbAlaBwsKgwRDOPC10fugJUMxAAh19gslhtgQgaIiiCtpCjAlUNtlDHFrBYVGAHAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-rl`, 21 "bytes"

```
gR+X1'/.TM_.'\TRt"¯_"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/PUg7wlBdXy/EN15PPSYkqETp0Pp4pf//DQ0NcAIuCGVoiKYIJGCIJGmIJmWIrBMuC@dgSiIxudBVI5uBohMBMF0Lk0A3FsI3RFD4jCVeElUaLfiwBROqJAb4r1uUAwA)

#### Explanation

```
g                      With -r flag, g is a list of all lines from stdin
 R                     In each line, replace
  +X1                   regex match of one or more 1's
                        with this callback function:
        TM_              Trim the first and last characters from the match
     '/.                 Prepend /
           .'\           Append \
              TR       Transliterate
                t      10
                 "¯_"  into ¯_
                       Autoprint, one list element per line (-l flag)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `aṠD`, 21 bytes

*-1 from Aaron Miller*

```
ƛĠƛ⌊ḣ$NpṫdJ`_¯\/`$İ;f
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=a%E1%B9%A0D&code=%C6%9B%C4%A0%C6%9B%E2%8C%8A%E1%B8%A3%24Np%E1%B9%ABdJ%60_%C2%AF%5C%2F%60%24%C4%B0%3Bf&inputs=0110%0A1111&header=&footer=%23%20Print%20nicely%0A%E1%B9%85%3B%E2%81%8B)

Heavily inspired by [@caird coinheringaahing's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225819/80050).
Outputs a list of lines containing a list of characters in each line. Uses the actual macron!

```
ƛĠƛ⌊ḣ$NpṫdJ`_¯\/`$İ;f    
ƛ                       For each line of (implicit) input...
 Ġƛ                ;     For each group of consecutive characters...
   ⌊                      Convert each character to an integer (so double and negate work)
      N                   Negate...
    ḣ$ p                    the first element of the group.
         d                Double...
        ṫ J                 the last element of the group.
                  İ       Index each element...
           `_¯\/`$          in "_¯\/" (negative indices start from the back)
                    f    Flatten the list of groups to a lists of chars
```

Comment: [21 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=aṠ&code=%C6%9B%C4%A0%C6%9B%E2%8C%8A%E1%B8%A3%24Np%E1%B9%ABdJ%60_-%5C%2F%60%24%C4%B0%3Bf&inputs=0110%0A1111&header=&footer=%23%20Print%20nicely%0A%E1%B9%85%3B%E2%81%8B)

Comment: You may as well use the D flag and add an overline...

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>48 44 43</sup> 41 bytes

```
'_^/\'{~(>./@,+:@g&.|.,:3*g=.1=2-/\,&0)"1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1ePj9GPUq@s07PT0HXS0rRzS1fRq9HSsjLXSbfUMbY109WN01Aw0lQz/a3KlJmfkK6QBNRsCoYGCjpUhmGX4HwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 56 bytes, 54 by the rules

```
gsub(0,"_")gsub(1,"/\\")gsub(/\\\//,"¯")gsub("/¯","/")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/vbg0ScNARyleSRPMNNRR0o@JgXKArBh9fR2lQ@uhAkr6QCZQhZLm//8GhAAXhDIEAhRxQ7gIF7oAgmuIYQZcCQoHiwpDNPO40PWhK0A1AwFw@AUmi9UWiKAhgiJoCzkqUNVgC3VsAYtFBXYAAA)

Substitutes: all `0` to `_`; all `1` to `/\`; all `\/` to `¯`; and, finally, all `/¯` to `/`.

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 52 bytes, 51 by the rules

```
gsub("01","0/")gsub(10,"\\0")gsub(0,"_")gsub(1,"¯")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/vbg0SUPJwFBJR8lAX0kTzDU00FGKiTGA8oCceJiEjtKh9Uqa//8bEAJcEMoQCFDEDeEiXOgCCK4hhhlwJSgcLCoM0czjQteHrgDVDATA4ReYLFZbIIKGCIqgLeSoQFWDLdSxBSwWFdgBAA)

Thanks to DLsoc for a 52 bytes/51 characters version.

Comment: @DLosc Nice! The simpler, the better! Thanks for sharing that. I'll edit my answer, giving credit to your code. I tried using [another algorithm](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/vbg0ScNARyleSbNaxcA2PTUPJKBvqGGopWmor6MUox8TYxgDBEo6SulKmrVg9YY6SofWK2ka/v9vQAhwQShDIEARN4SLcKELILiGGGbAlaBwsKgwRDOPC10fugJUMxAAh19gslhtgQgaIiiCtpCjAlUNtlDHFrBYVGAHAA), but with no success.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepge)

```
γε¬i¦¦…/ÿ\]JT„¯_‡
```

I/O as a multiline string.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OZzWw@tyTy07NCyRw3L9A/vj4n1CnnUMO/Q@vhHDQv//1dSUjIwMAQBAwMuIMOAC8TmMiAEoCogGpGAIVyEC10AwTXEMAOuBIWDRYUhmnlc6PrQFaCagQA4/AKTxWoLRNAQQRG0hRwVqGqwhTq2gMWiAjsAxvh/Xd28fN2cxKpKAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
γ           # Split the (implicit) input-string into equal adjacent parts
            #  i.e. "0110\n1111" → ["0","11","0","\n","1111"]
 ε          # Map each part to:
  ¬         #  Get its first character (without popping)
   i        #  If this is a 1:
    ¦¦      #   Remove two characters from this string
      …/ÿ\  #   Surround it with leading "/" and trailing "\"
 ]          # Close both the if-statement and map
            #  → ["0","/\","0","\n","/11\"]
  J         # Join everything back together
            #  → "0/\0\n/11\"
   T   ‡    # Then transliterate the characters "1" and "0"
    „¯_     # to the characters "¯" and "_"
            #  → "_/\_\n/¯¯\"
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>71 65</s> 61 bytes

```javascript
n=>n.replace(/./g,(e,i)=>+e?+n[i+1]?+n[i-1]?'-':'/':'\\':'_')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVDRCoMgFH33R1RM3X0d2D5kjRXNohEaNfb7ThZLdI5gB/Rwj@eei/fePJulnYfpwY29adcpZ1RpxKynsWk1kUL2BdHFQFXJ9ImZ88Dg8mbuGXN8xNKfqvLXFVPXWrPYUYvR9qQj9WEPaCXwiHTYFJQKoYSvjM0SFRkHJHko7UsNcUbAj798XrNTVhEC7U75xxF7clvPLTbjyKOm1L0A)

### How it works

Replaces every letter. For each letter in question: if the numerical representation is falsy (`0`) then replace with `_`, otherwise use a simple ternary to find the correct character to use. Uses `-` instead of macron, you know, just because. Saved 6 bytes by reorganizing and removing assignment to unused `a` variable. Then saved 4 thanks to a username by entirely getting rid of variables.

Comment: Why the b? [-4 bytes](https://tio.run/##nVDRCoMgFH33R1RM3X0d2D5kjRXNohEaNfb7ThZLdI5gB/Rwj@eei/fePJulnYfpwY29adcpZ1RpxKynsWk1kUL2BdHFQFXJ9ImZ88Dg8mbuGXN8xNKfqvLXFVPXWrPYUYvR9qQj9WEPaCXwiHTYFJQKoYSvjM0SFRkHJHko7UsNcUbAj798XrNTVhEC7U75xxF7clvPLTbjyKOm1L0A)

Comment: @Ausername thanks, did not realize that b was unused.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
ＷＳ⟦⪫Ｅ⪪ι0∧κ⪫/\×¯⁻Ｌκ²_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUHDM6@gtCS4pCgzL11DU1MhAMgo0Yj2ys/M0/BNLNAILsjJLNHI1FFQMlDS1FFwzEvRyNZRAEsr6cfEKOkohGTmphZrKB1aD2T7ZuaVFmv4pOall2RoZAPVG2mCAFB3vJJmrKb1//8GhAAXhDIEAhRxQ7gIF7oAgmuIYQZcCQoHiwpDNPO40PWhK0A1AwFw@AUmi9UWiKAhgiJoCzkqUNVgC3VsAYtFBY6Y@69blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⟦
```

Loop over each input string and print each output on a new line until an empty line is reached. (String array input format would have saved a byte.)

```
⪫Ｅ⪪ι0∧κ⪫/\×¯⁻Ｌκ²_
```

Split each string on `0`s, then replace each (non-empty) run of `1`s with a run of `¯`s wrapped in `/` and `\`, finally joining with `_`s.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
√E6∙²δ♪₧♂─Ç,áR0Z◄@╖
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=fb4536f9fdeb0d9e0bc4802ca052305a1140b7&i=%22%22%22%0A000000000000000000000000000000000%0A000000111100000000000001111100000%0A000000111110000000000111111000000%0A000000111111000000011111100000000%0A000000111111000001111110000000000%0A000000011111100011111100000000000%0A000000111111111111111100000000000%0A000000111101111111011110000000000%0A000000111100111110011110000000000%0A000000111111111111111110000000000%0A000000111111111111111110000000000%0A000000001111111111110000000000000%0A000000000001111100000000000000000%0A000000000000000000000000000000000%0A%22%22%22)

A regex based solution similar to the Pip and sed answers. Takes a full multiline string.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica,  74 bytes

```mathematica
StringReplace[#,{"101"->"\_/","01"->"_/","10"->"¯\\","0"->"_","1"->"¯"}]&
```

Comment: `StringReplace@{"101"->"\\_/","01"->"_/","10"->"¯\\","0"->"_","1"->"¯"}`